# Server IO Bottleneck - How can I reduce DB read/write and still persist my data?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, concurrency

We are developing a web application server with apache tomcat servers cluster and a load balancer. 
Our DB is mySQL and we use spring framework in our project.

One of the requirements is to be able to maintain a 10K concurrent users requests.

now, this leads to a real issue, since in each request handle we are doing the following:

1) begin a transaction

2) fetching data from DB (if needed)

3) transforming the data

4) persisting the data back to the DB

Now, obviously this is a major IO bottleneck for this process. If we used an in memory DB it will improve the performance significantly.

Whats more obvious is that nowadays servers can maintain high traffic and doing all the thing i noted above. so there must be a better architecture for processing these requests right?

Any ideas? references?

Thanks

Comment: Caching using ehcache?

Comment: But what happens if a tomcat node crashes? my logic is now gone with the cache?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an IO bottleneck in your databases accesses, you should use a cache. Common open source java caches are [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org), [Infinispan](http://infinispan.org) (formelly JBoss cache or [Hazelcast](http://hazelcast.org).

Caching can provide a dramatic performance improvement when the majority of requests are readonly and concern same data. The gain will be much lesser if every single request reads and writes a different element.

There are different cache architectures depending if data is mostly readonly accessed, if there is a single web server or a cluster, etc. Depending of your application requirement, your mileage will vary ... You will have to try yourself.

Comment: What about crashing of a tomcat node? all my data will be lost?

Comment: How can EHcache help when writing to the DB is the bottleneck?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut First the OP speaks of IO bottleneck (read + write ...). Ehcache is expected to improve performance at least on reads. And *depending on your consistency requirements*, Ehcache supports write behind mode that may still improve performances if many writes concern the same element. Of course, if every request concern a different element there is nothing to cache and the gain could only concern anicilliary data ...

Answer (score 1):

As @Serge pointed out, caching works greatly with read-only data. I never experienced a project requirement with 10k concurrent writes. If your requirement is to store session data in a way to recover from a node done, you can have a look at Apache Zookeeper. But since your question was more about database access reduction your best hint is to have a look at ehcache. It can be used as redundant storage node as well. Since you are usibg Spring have a look at the onboard @cachable features. Maybe yor solution is to cache the whole request.

Another option is to use Maria db in master/slave(s) mode.